# Query Selecting rows where data doesn't change

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of golf match-ups taken from Betfair's downloadable CSV files of historical data. They look like this:

```
event         selection
S. Garcia     Garcia
S. Garcia     Woods
P. Mickelson  Mickelson
P. Mickelson  Donald
E. Els        McIlroy
E. Els        Els
```

I need a query that provides the following output:

```
event         selection_a  selection_b
S. Garcia     Garcia       Woods
S. Garcia     Woods        Garcia
P. Mickelson  Mickelson    Donald
P. Mickelson  Donald       Mickelson
E. Els        McIlroy      Els
E. Els        Els          McIlroy
```

To conclude, the event name is just one of the players in the match-up. Within each match up there will be two players, how do I write a query that recognises that Garcia played Woods, Mickelson played Donald and Els played McIlroy?

Help! :-)

Comment: Maybe I just don't get your requirements. But, if you just need the "who played who" data and this not in your posted form, just query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE event <> selection`. Your sample output contains duplicate information. You can choose any of the players as event then.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I mistyped the question slightly, have edited it now. See above. The event field actually contains the players initial (e.g. S. Garcia) but the selection field has no initials. Unfortunately this is how the raw data is supplied by Betfair! So using <> doesn't work as the "S. Garcia" =/= "Garcia". Apologies for this 'clunky' question - the raw data from Befair is horrible but it's all I have! Thanks again MicSim!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    g.event,
    Min(g.selection) AS selection_a,
    Max(g.selection) AS selection_b
FROM Golf_matches AS g
GROUP BY g.event
UNION ALL
SELECT
    g.event,
    Max(g.selection),
    Min(g.selection)
FROM Golf_matches AS g
GROUP BY g.event
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: Ah, you got me by a minute :)

Comment: Epic. Thanks, muchly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Fairly sure that some SQL Ninja will come along and point out how bad this approach is but i've just been playing around with it. The approach i have so far is (included my declare but in your case just ignore it and replace @Match with your table name)

```
DECLARE @Match TABLE (
    eventName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    selection NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Match(eventName, selection)
VALUES ('S. Garcia', 'Garcia'),
       ('S. Garcia', 'Woods'),
       ('P. Mickelson', 'Mickelson'),
       ('P. Mickelson', 'Donald'),
       ('E. Els', 'McIlroy'),
       ('E. Els', 'Els')

SELECT M1.eventName, M1.selection AS SelectionA, M2.selection AS SelectionB 
    FROM @Match M1 
        INNER JOIN @Match M2 
          ON M1.eventName = M2.eventName
WHERE M1.selection <> M2.selection
```

Comment: I think this is a fine solution.

Comment: But replace `JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`. This is for Access.